# Xamarin notification popup

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm developing an app in xamarin, and I want to inform a user that WiFi isn't turned on in this kind of notification -https://puu.sh/tDAQG/b4d4c8ea07.JPG I was thinking about Alerts, but I'm not sure that I can reach this kind of effect. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was thinking about Alerts, but I'm not sure that I can reach this kind of effect. How can I do it?

It's just the original Toast Message of Android. You can show it easily through [Toast.MakeText](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText/p/Android.Content.Context/Java.Lang.ICharSequence/Android.Widget.ToastLength/).

ex:

```
Toast.MakeText(this, "This is a Toast Text", ToastLength.Short).Show();
```